# Opengl: error(#97) no program main found

Tags: opengl, glsl

this is the error I get when my application starts:

```
Vertex shader(s) failed to link, fragment shader(s) failed to link.
Vertex link error: INVALID_OPERATION.
ERROR: error(#97) No program main found
fragment link error: INVALID_OPERATION.
ERROR: error(#97) No program main found
```

I couldn't find any mistake, but the shaders are correctly (fully) loaded and compiled without any errors. Here are my shaders:

vertex shader:

```
#version 330
layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;
void main()
{
gl_Position = vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

fragment shader:

```
#version 330
out vec4 outputColor;
void main()
{
outputColor = vec4(1.0, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0);
}
```

Comment: I usually get errors like these when I didn't supply the correct shader source string to the `glShaderSource` function. Your shaders look correct, so check your source code string/char-array.

Comment: I don't think it is incorrect: glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &VSSource, NULL). it is usting a char array...

Comment: @TomS Can you step through in the debugger and see if VSSource contains the string you think it does at that time?

Comment: Ok thanks. I got the problem... The content was lost after loading. Works fine now... Thanks again!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Errors like these are usually caused by `glShaderSource` not receiving a correct source code string.

The cause of your issue is most likely that your shader code wasn't loaded properly and an incorrect string (or char array) is passed to `glShaderSource`